# Single image texture is not rendering correctly

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials

The problem is that when I render the image, the single image view texture seems like it getting scaled on the Z axis. It looks fine in the Cycles render preview. I UV unwrapped the cup and it seems to work fine up until the final render.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

[image: Single Image Texture not final rendering as expected]

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found it! It was because I was applying a Subdivision Surface Modifier to the render, but not in the preview